# Keyless control system does not respond

Tags: electrical, ford, keyless-entry

I have a 2000 Ford Excursion. Suddenly the remote system does not respond. I checked the battery of the keyless and replaced it, but it didn’t make any difference.

Are there any thoughts, or steps that would help me to check the system?

Answer (score 1):

The contacts on your key fob could be loose or corroded, preventing good contact with your battery.

Most likely, it is corrosion on the terminals inside the battery tray. You can clean that out by using a pencil eraser or some fine Emory cloth on the Positive (+) and Negative (-) terminals.

Sometimes, the metal tab that keeps the battery in electrical contact with the terminals gets mashed flat. If that happens, the battery will not be able to complete the electrical circuit.

Inside the battery compartment is a cheap piece of steel that acts as ground and provides pressure on the battery so that both sides stay in contact. If this piece of steel is not making good contact, you could try bending the little metal tab up slightly so that it has more pressure to provide to the battery.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try would be the vehicles 'second' key, if you have one. Secondly, most garages have a key tester which lights up when aimed at with the key. They respond to the key signals. This will prove the key(s) to be working or not.

If your key, and second key, both start the engine then the next step is a scan of the remote locking system to determine an area to check out.